# Error while reading spreadsheets (Google Data Studio)

Tags: google-sheets, google-bigquery, looker-studio

I have a Google Data Studio report that depends on a BigQuery view, and this view queries a spreadsheet.

When loading the dashboard, I get the following in **all** my charts:

[image]

When I click in `See details`, I get the following:

> BigQuery error: Invalid value: Error while reading table: test.test, error message: Failed to read the spreadsheet. Error code: RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED.

This error happens when I turn the report on for the first time, but then after some refreshes, the report works properly. Do you know how can I avoid this error?

Comment: This feels unexpected. You should be able to view the job history on the BigQuery project and see the job id for the failure query with RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED. You could then use such job id to contact Cloud Support or create ticket on BigQuery here: https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#trackers-list